# Blender casually freezes in any moment, not even overloading

Tags: interface

This usually happens between few seconds and ten minutes from when I open blender. The program stops working without showing any sign, not even "blender not responding" or the white screening. The CPU usage drops to 0% and I can't do anything with it. I'm using a not powerful laptop but it seems to me that it might be more of a software problem. Any idea?[image: screenshot of task manager]